# Is there any generic format which accepts multiple datetime formats with time zones?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datetime, time, java-8

present possible date time formats

Solution which accepts any kind of date time pattern like `yyyy-mm-ss'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, `yyyy-mm-ss'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` and many more with a single pattern which accepts these all patterns with a single format which makes code compatible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.